# failure of cabal install mime

Tags: haskell, cabal

I recently got the Haskell Platform for Mac OS X.  I've cabal installed a few packages, and then got this error, which I don't understand.  It seems to say I need version for 4 of base, but I do have that.

```
> cabal install mime  
Resolving dependencies...  
cabal: cannot configure mime-0.3.2. It requires base >=3 && <=4  
For the dependency on base >=3 && <=4 there are these packages: base-3.0.3.1  
and base-3.0.3.2. However none of them are available.  
base-3.0.3.1 was excluded because of the top level dependency base -any  
base-3.0.3.2 was excluded because of the top level dependency base -any
```

If I run `cabal info base` it shows many lines, but one of them is:

```
Versions installed: (4.3.1.0)
```

That doesn't satisfy the <=4 requirement of mime?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

4.3.1.0 is greater than 4 (which means 4.0.0.0).  In these cases I:

1. cabal unpack , edit the .cabal file to fix the base build dep, run `cabal install`
2. Send a politely worded e-mail to the maintainer.  I see it's Sigbjorn who has been hard to reach of late (I hear).  If he doesn't respond in a few weeks I'd consider updating the package yourself and send another polite e-mail (so long as the change is this small and trivial).